# Select dropdown option and submit form

Tags: python-requests

I have written code to get tables from a website, but I need to get access to an additional table by:

1. selecting a time frame from a dropdown.
2. submitting by clicking a 'filter' button.

The website is:

http://www.myfxbook.com/forex-market/currencies/nzdchf-historical-data

Inspect element on the dropdown shows this:

```
<select id="timeScales" class="selectField" onfocus="borderChange(this); "onblur="borderReturn(this);" style="border: 1px solid rgb(226, 225, 225);">
<option id="timeScale1" value="1">1 Minute</option>
<option id="timeScale5" value="5">5 Minutes</option>
<option id="timeScale15" value="15">15 Minutes</option>
<option id="timeScale30" value="30">30 Minutes</option>
<option id="timeScale60" value="60">1 Hour</option>
<option id="timeScale240" value="240">4 Hours</option>
<option id="timeScale1440" value="1440" selected="">1 Day</option>
<option id="timeScale10080" value="10080">1 Week</option>
<option id="timeScale43200" value="43200">1 Month</option>
```

From the timeframe dropdown, I want to select 4 hours, then click on the filter button.

I know how to get HTML using the requests.get method, but the problem I am having here is that the URL does not change when I select a dropdown value.

I have tried using requests.post, but I clearly don't know how to use it.
I am writing this program using "HOW TO AUTOMATE THE BORING STUFF USING PYTHON" as a tutorial, and the author does not explain how to programmatically click dropdown menus and click buttons.

He does explain the use of Selenium, but I have to repeat this process over 30 times, and having to open a new page every time would take too long.

I'd appreciate it if you could show how this could be achieved using requests module (if possible).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot *click* a button with requests, what you can do is mimic requests that get the data, when you choose a time period click filter an ajax request is made:

[image]

So to mimic that and get the html we need to pass the params below:

```
import requests

params = {"start": "2016-02-02 00:00",
          "end": "2016-06-20 00:00",
          "symbol": "NZDCHF",
          "timeScale": "240",
          "userTimeFormat": "0"}
head = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

url = "http://www.myfxbook.com/getHistoricalDataByDate.json"
js = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=head).json()
```

Then to get the table, access `js["content"]["historyData"]`:

```
print(js["content"]["historyData"])
```

Which gives you the table:

```
<table id="symbolMarket" class="sortable maxWidth center dataTable">
    <tr style="height:26px">
        <th sort="string">
            <a class="dotted font11 pointer">Date</a><span id="symbolMarketImg0"></span>
        </th>
        <th><span class="font11">Open</span></th>
        <th><span class="font11">High</span></th>
        <th><span class="font11">Low</span></th>
        <th width="63"><span class="font11">Close</span></th>
        <th sort="float" >
            <a class="dotted font11 pointer">Change (Pips)</a><span id="symbolMarketImg5"></span>
        </th>
        <th sort="float" >
            <a class="dotted font11 pointer">Change (%)</a><span id="symbolMarketImg6"></span>
        </th>
    </tr>
                <tr onmouseover="this.className='normalActive';" onmouseout="this.className='';">
            <td><span name="timeNZDCHF">Jun 20, 2016 00:00</span></td>
            <td><span name="openNZDCHF">0.67771</span></td>
            <td><span name="highNZDCHF">0.68133</span></td>
            <td><span name="lowNZDCHF">0.67771</span></td>
            <td><span name="closeNZDCHF">0.68057</span></td>
            <td class="bold"><span name="changePipsNZDCHF"><span class='green'>+28.6</span></span></td>
            <td class="bold"><span name="changePercentNZDCHF"><span class='green'>+0.42%</span></span></td>
        </tr>

  ......................................
```

You could easily parse the original page to get the values from the tag using *Beautifulsoup*:

```
In [7]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [8]: h = """<select id="timeScales" class="selectField" onfocus="borderChange(this); "onblur="borderReturn(this);" style="border: 1px solid rgb(226, 225, 225);">
   ...: <option id="timeScale1" value="1">1 Minute</option>
   ...: <option id="timeScale5" value="5">5 Minutes</option>
   ...: <option id="timeScale15" value="15">15 Minutes</option>
   ...: <option id="timeScale30" value="30">30 Minutes</option>
   ...: <option id="timeScale60" value="60">1 Hour</option>
   ...: <option id="timeScale240" value="240">4 Hours</option>
   ...: <option id="timeScale1440" value="1440" selected="">1 Day</option>
   ...: <option id="timeScale10080" value="10080">1 Week</option>
   ...: <option id="timeScale43200" value="43200">1 Month</option>"""

In [9]: soup = BeautifulSoup(h,"html.parser")

In [10]: durations = ([opt["value"] for opt in soup.select("#timeScales option")])

In [11]: durations
Out[11]: [u'1', u'5', u'15', u'30', u'60', u'240', u'1440', u'10080', u'43200']
```

But I don't see the logic behind that as the durations are in minutes and you would need to know your duration for the data.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same task for a [glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Apple-Reviews-E1138.htm) web, and for the filter dropdown, I try to select "intern", but they are in `div` tag instead of `option` Is there any way to select them via pass a param for requests? I've tried many ways...